Evaluate window does not show TDateTime as date format
My TDateTime field (retrieved with TClientDataSet.FieldByName().AsDateTime) shows as a float value in the Evaluate/Modify window, but not in the Watch window, of if I click Inspect:

A simple local TDateTime variable does show as a date.
Is this a bug?
Can I force it to show as a date?
This is Delphi 12, 64-bit.

Do you have all of the updates/patches installed for Delphi 12?  I have Patch 2 installed and when I try to reproduce what you have described, the Result field of the Evaluate dialog displays the formatted date/time value correctly.

@RemyLebeau Maybe that's it, I won't know until later (Office environment where 3 developers do a simultaneous upgrade). When that is done I'll update the question or post an answer.
